# kendo DropDownList trim long text for one line

Tags: drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, substring

I use Kendo UI Web DropDownList
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/dropdownlist/index.html

(document in http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/web/dropdownlist/overview)

When the text is too long, DropDownList auto set newline for the item, maybe 3 lines for this item. However, I want one item per line. How can I trim  or show like header (contain '..' at the end) for long text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try defining the following CSS:

```
li.k-item {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}
```

You might limit it to only one element by doing:

```
var dd = $("#list2").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: titles
}).data("kendoDropDownList");
dd.list.addClass("ob-ellipsis");
```

and the CSS as

```
.ob-ellipsis li.k-item {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/Yupwj/

Answer (score 2):

I like OnaBai's answer (of course I always do), but another option is to use a custom template for the text property and handle truncating yourself.

```
<script id="textTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    # if (data.name.length > 5) { #
        <span>${data.name.substring(0, 5)}...</span>
    # } else { #
        <span>${data.name}</span>
    # } #
</script>
```

See sample http://jsbin.com/kotur/1/edit